# Securing Comunication between Adobe Air and Server

Tags: air

I am developing a site that has a Flex app that uses php to communicate with a MYSQL database and I intend to get an SSL certificate to secure the communication. Subscribers to the service that I intend to provide will have an admin panel built with adobe air that will also need to communicate with the database. My question is how do I secure that communication? Do I need a different SSL cert for each subscriber? I hope not!

Answer (score 1):

SSL will only protect the connection between the clients machine and the server from trivial snooping by 3rd parties.

It won't, for example, protect your database if it is open to the internet publically. You'll need to secure the connection for that by having a server interface to it, instead of having it open directly. This interface is typically called a 'webservice' or similar. I can't comment much more because I'm not at all familiar with flex.

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't really answer my question ie how do I secure data that is being transmitted between my server and the adobe air applications that are on subscribers desktops.

Answer (score 1):

In AIR, it should work the same for your Flex app in the browser. If you communicate over an HTTPS URL, the data is encrypted. There's nothing special you need to do.